# Most debugging options greyed out in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've ran into a nasty NullPointerException in my code, it's nothing too bad, I should be able to fix it quite easily with some breakpoints and "Step Into".

The only problem is, almost all of the debugging options are greyed out for me in Eclipse, I've used them before and they worked fine, but now when I need them the most, they're not working!

I looked on the internet and tried some things like running eclipse with -clean, restarting, opening debug perspective, making sure skip breakpoints were disabled.. None of which worked unfortunately.

I'm guessing it's just me missing something really obvious but any help fixing this would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, It says "terminated", so your program must have ended execution.
That's why all the buttons are greyed out.

The exit value is 1, which indicates abnormal end to an execution of a program (program aborted without reaching the end). Try placing breakpoints earlier in the code to find out where it stops executing.

Comment: That would make sense that I can't step into if it's terminated. What is weird though is that Eclipse says the error occurs on line 42, I created multiple breakpoints before line 42 (on lines 37, 38, and 39 to be precise), all of these are in the same method body as the error but the breakpoints are being ignored.

Comment: Make sure you "Debug" not "Run the application (Debug is the bug icon).

Comment: That did it! Of course it was me that was the problem, thanks I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Your application already terminated. The debugging options are only enabled, when an actual debug application is running.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I replied to Tomasz who had similar thoughts